# NODE JS Knex connecting to Postgresql on Gcloud

Tags: node.js, postgresql, cloud, gcloud, knex.js

Right now, I am trying to get my App Engine (Flex Environment) on Google Cloud to be able to connect to the postgreSQL server on the same project.
I have given the service account listed under the SQL database overview the Cloud SQL Client role. When executing, my knex instance is configured as such

```
const KNEX_CON = {
user: USERNAME,
    password: PASSWORD,
    database: DATABASE,
    host: "/cloudsql/PROJECT_ID:us-central1:INSTANCE"
}

const knexInstance = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: KNEX_CON,
    })
```

I also have the app.yaml to `beta_settings: cloud_sql_instances: "PROJECT_ID:us-central1:INSTANCE"`

I have been going over the documentation and every stackoverflow answer I can find. Nothing I do is working. Any Knex instance running within the App Engine fails. Any Express endpoint that does not require a knex instance works perfectly. I keep getting the same error/timeout that happens when I try to connect to an SQL server on Gcloud without whitelisting my IP address. Please help me.

Comment: Normally I'd expect "host" to be an IP address or server/dns name. But maybe that's the sort of format that works with knex/glcoud. Are you sure that bit is correct?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine and other Stack overflow questions have specified to use a UNIX socket. For MYSQL, that knex setting is actually called socket, but for postgres, it needs to be under host.

Comment: Have you console.log'ed out your config?  I don't think environment variables are replaced in strings like you have for "host".  Instead, you should create an environment variable for it, like `export PG_HOST="/cloudsql/$PROJECT_ID:us-central1:$INSTANCE"` and use "host": PG_HOST.

Answer (score 0):

To use Cloud SQL in App Engine Flex, make sure you chose the 2nd generation instance. I came across this set of [directions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/postgres/knex) for both App Engine standard and App Engine Flex that might help you get your Next.JS connected.